# Postman returning 404 for REST API on correct path

Tags: spring, rest, tomcat, postman, http-status-code-404

I have created a Rest API. I was testing it on postman yesterday and it was working fine, today it keeps returning a 404, the file paths haven't changed so that can't be wrong. I am using tomcat, and my xampp is on.
It postman is returning the correct data for another application I have.

The path I am trying to test is

```
http://localhost:8080/Assignment2C/breweries
```

the method I'm trying to test is

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/breweries")
public class Breweries_Controller {

    @Autowired
    Breweries_Service service;

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
    public Resources<Breweries> getAllBreweries() {
        List<Breweries> allBreweries = service.getAllBreweries();
        for (Breweries b : allBreweries) {
            int id = b.getResourceId();
            Link self = linkTo(this.getClass()).slash(id).withSelfRel();
            b.add(self);
            linkTo(methodOn(this.getClass()).getBrewerie(id));
        }
        Link link = linkTo(this.getClass()).withSelfRel();
        Resources<Breweries> result = new Resources<Breweries>(allBreweries, link);
        return result;

    }
```

I am using JPA to connect to the database.

the project structure is

[image]

the config file is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="Assignment2C" />



    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/views</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/sd4-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: Are you sure application is started correctly?

Comment: Is your application context correct?  What is Assignment2C?

Comment: @mentallurg I'm right-clicking the project and selecting run and builds fine in the console, is there anything else I'm meant to do?

Comment: @doct03 Assignment2C is the name of the project, I've added more info to the question I forgot to add

Comment: insteasd of  http://localhost:8080/Assignment2C/breweries try http://localhost:8080/2C/breweries and make sure you send a GET request

Comment: @javaNoob http://localhost:8080/Assignment2C/breweries is still giving a 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i set the base_package to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="main" />
```

it works

Answer (score 0):

try to give path to the get mapping also

```
   @GetMapping("/getAll")
```

you url will should look like

this:
    http://localhost:8080/Assignment2C/breweries/getAll
Or 
    http://localhost:8080/2C/breweries/getAll

Comment: sadly that didn't work either, I think its a tomcat/apache issue

Comment: I have changed the config to Assignment2C and it still doesn't work